# bash: colorized man page

Tags: bash, shell, colors, pager, man

Where do I have to take a look at in the system to colorize the man pages?

The man pages are viewed with less, so I tried adding the following lines to my .bashrc to change the colors: (Which works fine, btw.)

```
 #
 #   L E S S   C O L O R S   F O R   M A N   P A G E S
 #

 # CHANGE FIRST NUMBER PAIR FOR COMMAND AND FLAG COLOR
 # currently 0;33 a.k.a. brown, which is dark yellow for me 
    export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\E[0;33;5;74m'  # begin bold

 # CHANGE FIRST NUMBER PAIR FOR PARAMETER COLOR
 # currently 0;36 a.k.a. cyan
    export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\E[0;36;5;146m' # begin underline

 # don't change anything here
    export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\E[1;31m'       # begin blinking
    export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\E[0m'           # end mode
    export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\E[0m'           # end standout-mode
    export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[38;5;246m'    # begin standout-mode - info box
    export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\E[0m'           # end underline

 #########################################
 # Colorcodes:
 # Black       0;30     Dark Gray     1;30
 # Red         0;31     Light Red     1;31
 # Green       0;32     Light Green   1;32
 # Brown       0;33     Yellow        1;33
 # Blue        0;34     Light Blue    1;34
 # Purple      0;35     Light Purple  1;35
 # Cyan        0;36     Light Cyan    1;36
 # Light Gray  0;37     White         1;37
 #########################################
```

To my shame I have to admit that I did not find out what the second number pair meant, i.e. the `5;74` and the `5;146`.

Can someone clarify that further?

Comment: What is it with the close votes? I have known the wikipedia link before and still i have no idea what the order of the sequence means. Trial and error and setting different values did not help me at all. A simple "go RTFM" does not help me here.

Comment: You gotta be kidding me... this is just great! Where is this stuff documented? I looked in the BASH and LESS man pages but could not find the LESS_TERMCAP string.

Comment: OK, found this for starters: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119/colors-in-man-pages

Comment: This: "`for name [ [ in [ word ... ] ] ; ] do list ; done`" makes more sense now, in color... 8-)

Comment: @ysap : Haven't seen that links, and cannot remember where I found this. Put this here for documentation purposes and asked about the escape sequences in the process. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\E[0;33;5;74m'  # begin bold
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\E[0;36;5;146m' # begin underline
```

In these two cases, all the colors and attributes are reset (0), the foreground color is switched to yellow/brown (33) or cyan (36), then blinking is turned on (5), and then something else also happens (74 or 146) which are probably undefined and not desired.

```
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[38;5;246m'
```

This one's different, because 38 takes additional numeric parameters. It stands for extended foreground color (and similarly 48 would be the same for background), and if followed by a 5 as the next parameter (which doesn't have anything to do with blinking this time) the third number specifies the color's index (from 0 to 255: 16 standard legacy colors, followed by a 6x6x6 RGB cube, followed by 24 grayscale colors), see e.g. [here](http://www.calmar.ws/vim/256-xterm-24bit-rgb-color-chart.html).

Certain terminal emulators also support direct arbitrary RGB colors, in that case 38 should be followed by 2, and then by three decimal numbers in the 0-255 range for R, G, B respectively, e.g. #BADA55 is

```
\E[38;2;186;218;85m
```

Comment: It's quite bad that you can't know which `;` stands for additional parameters of a previous one and which stands for a brand new without looking at the exact numbers. So it was recommended that additional parameters should be separated by a `:` instead. For example, to reset everything, then switch to color #246, and also turn on blinking, instead of `0;38;5;246;5` you'd say `0;38:5:246;5`. Unfortunately it's supported by even fewer terminals.

Answer (score 5):

"\e[...m" is the SGR CSI code. The Wikipedia page on "ANSI escape code", ["CSI codes" section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes) describes them.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html and the wikipedia link I came to the conclusion that `5` means `5  Blink: Slow less than 150 per minute`.

The last numbers sound like this:

```
 If 88- or 256-color support is compiled, the following apply. 
 P s = 3 8 ; 5 ; P s → Set foreground color to the second P s . 
 P s = 4 8 ; 5 ; P s → Set background color to the second P s .
```

Also it seems that the amount of numbers is not important, just their chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a bash solution, but still relevant, 
use:

> PAGER=~/bin/vimpager

and drop this into ~/bin:
https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager